# What does "[TRUNCATED]" mean in the Tinn-R console?

Tags: r, tinn-r

I tried to create a sum function that ignores NA values for practicing. My code is:

```
my.sum <- function(x){
sum.f = 0
y <- !is.na(x)
z <- x[y]
n <- length(z)
  for (i in 1 : n) {
      sum.f <- sum.f  + z[i]
            }
return(sum.f)
}
```

When I run the code directly in R Console, I see the code as expected:

```
> > my.sum <- function(x){
> + sum.f = 0
> + y <- !is.na(x)
> + z <- x[y]
> + n <- length(z)
> +   for (i in 1 : n) {
> +       sum.f <- sum.f  + z[i]
> +             }
> + return(sum.f)
> + }
```

But when I run the code in Tinn-R, I see this instead:

```
my.sum <- function(x){
> + sum.f = 0
> + y <- !is.na(x)
> + z <- x[y]
> + n <- length(z)
> +   for (i in 1 : n) {
> +       sum.f <- sum.f  + z[i]
> +             .... [TRUNCATED]
```

What is the meaning of `[TRUNCATED]` in the Tinn-R console and why did I get it?

Comment: It seems that Tinn-R has some limit on amount of output and yours was truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of Tinn-R if the option **R echo (on/off) is on**, when you send a selection, if it has more than one line, Tinn-R send to R interpreter an instruction like this:

```
> source(.paths[5], echo=TRUE, max.deparse.length=60)
```

The argument **max.deparse.length** control the maximal number of characters output for the deparse of a single expression. In my example it is 60. So after 60 character echoed R print:

```
>.... [TRUNCATED]
```

You can easely change this value in Tinn-R at: **Options/Application/R/Basic**
in the topic: *Option (max.deparse.length (echo=TRUE))*